# Including deprecated Facebook header folder gives error

Tags: facebook, ios5, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/) link. But I am really stuck here, and i am getting 20 errors of duplicity and redefinition.

It happens when I replaced facebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h to Facebook.h . Before that as said in the tutorial I include a folder "Deprecated header" from Facebook sdk.

According to this Facebook tutorial:

> Step 2: Sending the request
>
> To invoke the Facebook dialogs you must reference the Facebook deprecated headers. The headers can be found here ~Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/Versions/A/DeprecatedHeaders. Drag the whole DeprecatedHeaders folder and deselect the "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)" option to add the headers as a reference.
>
> Now you can make the required code changes. In your app delegate import the Facebook.h header file and replace the Facebook framework <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h> import declaration:
>
> ```
> #import "Facebook.h"
> ```
>
> This will allow you to make call to the FBDialog classes. The Facebook.h header includes the <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h> header files. If you have any problems with Xcode recognizing the Facebook.h file just close and reopen your Xcode project.
>
> In the app delegate header file, declare a property that will hold the Facebook instance:
>
> ```
> @property (strong, nonatomic) Facebook *facebook;
> ```
>
> In the app delegate implementation file, synthesize the Facebook property:
>
> ```
> @synthesize facebook = _facebook;
> ```

As soon as I do this, I get errors and not able to compile.

Comment: just make sure you are using latest facebook sdk 3.1 to integrate the facebook to your app , check out this http://developers.facebook.com/features/whats-new-ios-sdk-3.1/

Comment: Hi , I am using the latest version of facebook sdk .. but now i think that if its not working then i should prefer old one ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

solved it finally.

I removed errors using following steps:

i replaced #import "FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h" with #import "FBSession.h" everywhere in my project. And other thing i Only used #import "facebook.h " in Appdelegate.h. This solved the error for me and i did nothing extra

Hope this would help someone here

Comment: Actually, simply replacing the import for `<FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>` by `"Facebook.h"` does the trick, no need to include `FBSession.h` separately.

Comment: @rakesh: Please elaborate your answer. I'm facing the same issue and replacing the import for <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h> by "Facebook.h" doesn't do the trick for me.

Comment: i replaced #import "FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h" with #import "FBSession.h" everywhere in my project. And other thing i Only used #import "facebook.h " in Appdelegate.h. This solved the error for me and i did nothing extra. Let me know if this helps you

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. Thanks a lot for your help. It worked wonders. Cheers!